# Keyboard cannot present view controllers warning

Tags: ios, ios11, autofill

When tapping the "Passwords" button at the top of the keyboard for login/password Autofill, this warning prints to the console log:

```
Keyboard cannot present view controllers (attempted to present <UIKeyboardHiddenViewController_Autofill: 0x10a618e90>)
```

However, the Autofill view controller does present successfully after authenticating with FaceID/TouchID.

Why does this warning appear, and is there a way to resolve it?

Comment: Have you determined how to understand whether password button is tapped on keyboard?

Comment: Hi Emrah. I have not.

Comment: @monkee Have you found any solution for this? I am facing this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73898904/sfapppasswordsavingviewcontroller-that-is-already-being-presented-by-uikeyb for the same reason.