# <_SFAppPasswordSavingViewController:> that is already being presented by <UIKeyboardHiddenViewController_Save>

Tags: swift, ipad, crash, orientation, keyboard-events

I am working on an iPad application that has both Portrait and Landscape orientation. The issue that I am facing is regarding the the popup presentation that iPad shows you for saving password while you log-in in the application.

[image]

Now, when the pop-up is presented, at that moment if I try to rotate the device, the application crashes with the message

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
Application tried to present modally a view controller <_SFAppPasswordSavingViewController: 0x107be7230> that is already being presented by <UIKeyboardHiddenViewController_Save: 0x107a49190>.
```

Now, the problem is that `SFAppPasswordSavingViewController` presentation is not controlled by me. Also `UIKeyboardHiddenViewController_Save`,is something I am not controlling.

Please help me out on how to solve this issue or let me know if I am missing anything.

This is how I am presenting Login screen in my application.

```
guard let loginVC = LoginVC.loadFromXIB() else {
    Log.w("LoginVC could not be loaded")
    return
}
let navVC = PopNavigationController(rootViewController: loginVC)
UIWindow.key?.replaceRootViewControllerWith(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Here `replaceRootViewControllerWith` is a custom function that is an extension on UIWindow.

```
extension UIWindow {

    func replaceRootViewControllerWith(_ replacementController: UIViewController,
                                       animated: Bool,
                                       completion: (() -> Void)?) {
        let snapshotImageView = UIImageView(image: self.snapshot())
        self.addSubview(snapshotImageView)

        let dismissCompletion = { [weak self] in // dismiss all modal view controllers
            self?.rootViewController = replacementController
            self?.bringSubviewToFront(snapshotImageView)
            if animated {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
                    snapshotImageView.alpha = 0
                }, completion: { (_) -> Void in
                    snapshotImageView.removeFromSuperview()
                    completion?()
                })
            } else {
                snapshotImageView.removeFromSuperview()
                completion?()
            }
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            if self?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController != nil {
                self?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: dismissCompletion)
            } else {
                dismissCompletion()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show few lines of codes you are using for login? Did you present view controller?

Comment: @ShamimHossain I have updated the question to show some presentation codes. Please have a look and let me know. Thanks.